# SQL - downloads everything even thou I have requested it to download only %LIKE%

Tags: php, sql

I am working on a simple attendance system all is working but.
on this particular PHP script, there is a problem, it should only download the load data from SQL but when I click  $_GET['search_download']  it downloads all the data from SQL.
ADDITIONAL INFO: I am using a GitHub repository that enables me to convert PHP script to PDF

```
            <?php
                
                session_start();

                if(isset($_SESSION['role']) && $_SESSION['role'] == 'admin'){
                
                } else {
                    echo header('Location: ../../event_attendance_system/index.php');
                    
                }
                
                include_once ('../../event_attendance_system/SQL/connections.php');
                $sql_connection = connection();

                $search = $_GET['search_id'];
                $sql ="SELECT * FROM guest_table WHERE firstname LIKE '%$search%'  OR lastname LIKE '%$search%' OR email LIKE '%$search%' ORDER BY ID DESC";  
                $guest = $sql_connection->query($sql) or die ($sql_connection->error);
                $row =  $guest -> fetch_assoc(); 
                
                error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
                    
                if($row == null){
                    $empty ='<p class="text-danger text-uppercase text-center">Data is not registered in the data base</p>';
                }
                
                

                
                if (isset($_GET['search_download'])){
                    require_once __DIR__ . '../../vendor/autoload.php';
                    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
                    $data = '';
                    // this the github repository I am talking about. 
                    // I do not understand why this downloads all the data from SQL when I have already set this  
                    //  $sql ="SELECT * FROM guest_table WHERE firstname LIKE '%$search%'  OR lastname LIKE '%$search%' OR email LIKE '%$search%' ORDER BY ID DESC";  

                    $data .='<table>';
                    $data .='<thead>';
                    $data .='<tr>';
                    $data .='<th >#</th>';
                    $data .='<th >First name</th>';
                    $data .='<th >Last name</th>';
                    $data .='<th >Email </th>';
                    $data .='<th >Date and time </th>';
                    $data .='</tr>';
                    $data .='</thead>';
                    $data .='<tbody>';
                                do { 
                    $data .='<tr>';
                    $data .='<th>'.$row['ID']. '</th>';
                    $data .='<td>'.$row['firstname'].'</td>';
                    $data .='<td>'.$row['lastname'].'</td>';
                    $data .='<td>'.$row['email'].'</td>';
                    $data .='<td>'.$row['date_time'].'</td>';
                    $data .='</tr>';
                                }while($row = $guest -> fetch_assoc()); 
                    $data .='</tbody>';
                    $data .='</table>';  

                    $mpdf ->WriteHTML($data);
                    $mpdf ->Output('data.pdf','D');
                
                }
                
            ?>


            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                <title>Home page</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../event_attendance_system/css/global.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../event_attendance_system/css/admin.css">
            </head>
            <body>
                <div class="pt-5">
                    <div class="container-fluid shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
                        <p class="admin_message">Participants Details</p>
                        <div class="search_container">
                            <form action="../../event_attendance_system/php/search.php" method="get">
                                <input type="search" id="form1" class="form-control"  name="search_id" placeholder="search here"/>
                                <label class="pt-3"><a href="../../event_attendance_system/index.php">Back To Home Page</a></label>
                                <label><a href="../../event_attendance_system/php/admin_page.php">Show All</a></label>
                                <label><a href="../../event_attendance_system/download_search.php" name="search_download">Download data</a></label>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <table class="table">
                                <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            
                                            <th scope="col">#</th>
                                            <th scope="col">First name</th>
                                            <th scope="col">Last name</th>
                                            <th scope="col">Email </th>
                                            <th scope="col">Date and time </th>
                                        </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <?php do {?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="row"><?php echo $row['ID'];?></th>
                                        <td><?php echo $row['firstname']; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $row['lastname']; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $row['date_time']; ?></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <?php }while($row = $guest -> fetch_assoc()); ?>
                                </tbody>
                        </table> 
                        <?php if(isset($empty)) { ?>
                            <div>
                            <?php echo $empty; ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php } ?> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Did you make a debug output of the `$sql` variable, and checked if everything looks alright in there? Did you test that SQL statement via copy&paste in phpMyAdmin or similar? And FYI, this is of course open to SQL injection.

Comment: Hi

I have solved this problem It was just the ID that needs to be added in the download option.

Thank you for taking your time in checking this code, this is nothing serious is just simple project also thank you for pointing out the SQL injection that is something that I will be working.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured this out. All I have to do is to add an ID on the download option of the code and it worked like magic.